# LAN only personal cloud file server (Windows 7 laptop)

Tags: networking, lan, cloud-storage, personal-data

I have a Windows 7 laptop, currently running a music/video server (Emby). I have this media server running through a wireless/LAN router that is NOT connected to the internet. I am wondering if there is a piece of software I can install on this laptop that will allow me to interact with the files stored there like Google Drive (upload/download/move/delete) from any device on my LAN network?

Comment: Would Windows' built-in file sharing not do all that?  That'd be the simplest setup.  Unless I'm misinterpreting your question...

Comment: @DarkMoon  Windows file sharing only works across LAN with other Windows computers. I need a solution with a web/app interface that is compatible with several operating systems, across LAN. It'd be nice for it to be similar to the Google Drive/Dropbox interface, but running from my personal computer strictly offline.

Comment: Windows file sharing isn't just for Windows; Linux, Mac, and Android (and probably iOS as well, but that one I'm not sure about) all can browse Windows shares. But no, there isn't a web interface.

Comment: @DarkMoon I was not aware that Windows file sharing worked across different OS'es, I am however very familiar with how WFS operates, and I do not like it. I have taken it upon myself to find a suitable file hosting alternative. I will write an answer based on the best solution I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viable solution found: Tonido personal cloud.

Although Tonido requires an active internet connection upon first startup, from that point on it can be operated fully offline. Tonido offers several desktop and mobile applications for connecting to the cloud server, as well as a convenient web interface that is compatible with most modern web browsers.

Tonido, as well as all of it's dedicated apps are free for unlimited use.